# How to loop through a list of table names and see if a specific value in a column exists?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have produced a table in SQL with a list of tables.  This list of tables is stored under the column 'table_name'.  I want to loop through each entry under 'table_name' and return a 1 if that table has a value in a specific column or 0 if that table does not have a value in a specific column.

How would I do that?

Edited With sample data

```
table_name
tabel1
table2
table3
table4
```

Pseudo Code

```
For i in table_name
if count(table_name["col_name"] = "value") > 0
return 1
else 
return 0
```

Comment: You can *only* achieve this dynamic SQL. Honestly, the fact you want to do this sounds like a design flaw and an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: I am trying to understand the data in my DB more.  I already have a list of tables that I know have the column.  I just want to know which of those tables have a specific entry.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Loop through all tables and get the max value from a specific column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38559293/sql-loop-through-all-tables-and-get-the-max-value-from-a-specific-column)

Comment: Are you searching for a fixed column name, or all columns for the specified table and value?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
drop table if exists #t
create table #t (A int)
insert into #t
select 1

drop table if exists #t2
create table #t2 (A int)
insert into #t2
select 0


drop table if exists #tables
create table #tables (tab varchar(100))

declare
    @loop table (rn int, tab varchar(100))
declare
    @res table (cnt int)
declare
    @i int=1
    ,@tab varchar (100)=''
    ,@query nvarchar (max)

insert into #tables
select '#t'
union all
select '#t2'

insert into @loop
select ROW_NUMBER () over (partition by (select 1) order by tab),tab from #tables

while  @i<=(select max(rn) from @loop)
begin
    select @tab=tab from @loop where rn=@i

    set @query='select count(*) from '+@tab+' where a=1'

    insert into @res
    exec(@query)

    if (select cnt from @res)>0  select 'Exists' else select 'Not Exists'
    delete @res
    set @i=@i+1

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a singular column/value in question, you can try the following in SSMS:

```
DECLARE @Tables table ( table_name varchar(50) );
INSERT INTO @Tables VALUES
    ( 'Child' ), ( 'COS' ), ( 'CustomData' ), ( 'Misc' ), ( 'Misc2' );

DECLARE 
    @col varchar(50) = 'id', -- column to be queried
    @val varchar(50) = '1',  -- value to be queried
    @sql varchar(MAX) = ''   -- important! set to empty string;

    SELECT
        @sql = @sql + CASE WHEN LEN( @sql ) > 0 THEN ' UNION ' ELSE '' END 
            + 'SELECT ' + QUOTENAME( table_name, '''' ) + ' AS [table_name], COUNT(*) AS [value_count] FROM [' + table_name + '] WHERE [' + @col + ']=' + QUOTENAME( @val, '''' )
    FROM @Tables t WHERE EXISTS (

        SELECT * FROM sys.columns c WHERE c.object_id = OBJECT_ID( t.table_name ) AND c.[name] = @col
    
    );

    EXEC( @sql );
```

In my environment this returns:

```
+------------+-------------+
| table_name | value_count |
+------------+-------------+
| Child      |           1 |
| Misc       |           1 |
| Misc2      |           0 |
+------------+-------------+
```

This is the (beautified) dynamic SQL created:

```
SELECT 'Child' AS [table_name], COUNT(*) AS [value_count] FROM [Child] WHERE [id]='1'
UNION
SELECT 'Misc' AS [table_name], COUNT(*) AS [value_count] FROM [Misc] WHERE [id]='1'
UNION
SELECT 'Misc2' AS [table_name], COUNT(*) AS [value_count] FROM [Misc2] WHERE [id]='1'
```

The `EXISTS` in the `WHERE` clause eliminates any tables that do not have the column in question, and thereby any errors related to it.